# Why I am unable to delete a database record using a NodeJS code?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Please check the below code

```
// This is a CRON job

// This function will walk through the FCM records everyday and remove records older than 2 months
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.fcmManager = async (event, context) => {

    const connection = await pool.getConnection();
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    connection.config.namedPlaceholders = true;


        try {
            await connection.beginTransaction();

            //Get the current datetime
            const currentDateTime = new Date();
            currentDateTime.setMonth(currentDateTime.getMonth() - 2);

            console.log(currentDateTime.toLocaleDateString());

            //Delete the records
            const deleteFcmSql = "DELETE FROM fcm WHERE date_created < :date ";
            const deleteFcmResult = await connection.query(deleteFcmSql, {date:currentDateTime});

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            await connection.rollback();
            return errorCodes.save_failed;
            
        }
        finally{
            connection.release();
        }

    
};
```

In my database I have a records which is created on `2022-07-20 05:01:41`. So technically, this record needs to get deleted because this code `console.log(currentDateTime.toLocaleDateString());` prints the date `7/21/2022`.

However, nothing get deleted and no change is taking place in the database. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Just had to add the following code line

```
await connection.commit();
```